# Python Dataframe: Get list of cells of values >=x and the corresponding (row,col)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Created a correlation matrix df=dfx.corr(). About 2000x2000, so could brute force a nested loop, but am looking for most efficient way to create a new df of each cell where value >= x and the (row,column), e.g. suppose x=.6, and columns are ['A',....,'Z'], something like*:

| index | value | row | col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | .756 | A | Z |
| 1 | .687 | B | Q |
| 2 | .897 | X | M |

- row,col could be a list, tuple, or whatever, as long as can be accessed later

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume this input:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(10,10)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'), index=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
```

```
          A         B         C         D         E         F         G         H         I         J
A  0.548814  0.715189  0.602763  0.544883  0.423655  0.645894  0.437587  0.891773  0.963663  0.383442
B  0.791725  0.528895  0.568045  0.925597  0.071036  0.087129  0.020218  0.832620  0.778157  0.870012
C  0.978618  0.799159  0.461479  0.780529  0.118274  0.639921  0.143353  0.944669  0.521848  0.414662
D  0.264556  0.774234  0.456150  0.568434  0.018790  0.617635  0.612096  0.616934  0.943748  0.681820
E  0.359508  0.437032  0.697631  0.060225  0.666767  0.670638  0.210383  0.128926  0.315428  0.363711
F  0.570197  0.438602  0.988374  0.102045  0.208877  0.161310  0.653108  0.253292  0.466311  0.244426
G  0.158970  0.110375  0.656330  0.138183  0.196582  0.368725  0.820993  0.097101  0.837945  0.096098
H  0.976459  0.468651  0.976761  0.604846  0.739264  0.039188  0.282807  0.120197  0.296140  0.118728
I  0.317983  0.414263  0.064147  0.692472  0.566601  0.265389  0.523248  0.093941  0.575946  0.929296
J  0.318569  0.667410  0.131798  0.716327  0.289406  0.183191  0.586513  0.020108  0.828940  0.004695
```

Simply unstack, select and get the index:

```
s = df.unstack()
s[s>0.6].index
```

output (row, column):

```
MultiIndex([('A', 'B'),
            ('A', 'C'),
            ('A', 'H'),
            ('B', 'A'),
            ('B', 'C'),
            ...
            ('J', 'I')],
           )
```

Comment: Interesting first step. Ok, and I said could be in a tuple, but the corresponding values are not retrieved. So, as a MultiIndex operations looking to count or average, etc., the values like 'A''s or 'J's won't work?